# Making a variable depend on the value of another in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automated-tests, conditional-statements, factory-bot

I have the following problem. I have a model in which there is a validation of a variable (amount) depending on the value of another enum variable (kind).

```
class ScopeChange < ActiveRecord::Base

enum kind: [ :add, :remove, :change ]

validates :amount, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 } , if: "self.add?"
validates :amount, :numericality => { :less_than_or_equal_to => -1 } , if: "self.remove?"

end
```

And I want to create a Factory that builds this, I have tried putting the if statement inside the actual creator of the variable (it should be an if elsif else statment, this was just made for testing)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sprint_scope_change do
    association :sprint
    kind { Faker::Number.between(0,2) }
    amount { kind == :add ? Faker::Number.between(-7,7) }
    date { Faker::Date.between(sprint.start_date, sprint.end_date) }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end
end
```

which didn't work, it completely ignored the if statement and just created a random number between -7 and 7. The next thing I tried was making a variable outside the factory :sprint_scope_change and inside it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :sprint_scope_change do

    sprint_scope_change.kind = Faker::Number.between(0,2)

    sprint_scope_change.amount = if sprint_scope_change.kind == 0
      Faker::Number.between(1,7)
    elsif sprint_scope_change.kind == 1
      Faker::Number.between(-7,-1)
    else
      Faker::Number.between(-7,7)
    end

    association :sprint
    kind { kind }
    amount { amount }
    date { Faker::Date.between(sprint.start_date, sprint.end_date) }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end
end
```

which worked in a way, but it gave the exact same value everytime I called the Factory. The last way that I tried was with a before(:create), but now the program just explodes and "stack level is too deep", I tried to reproduce some examples that I've seen but something is definitely wrong:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

factory :sprint_scope_change do
  before(:create) { |sprint_scope_change|

    sprint_scope_change.kind = Faker::Number.between(0,2)

    sprint_scope_change.amount = if sprint_scope_change.kind == 0
      Faker::Number.between(1,7)
    elsif sprint_scope_change.kind == 1
      Faker::Number.between(-7,-1)
    else
      Faker::Number.between(-7,7)
    end
  }

  association :sprint
  kind { kind }
  amount { amount }
  date { Faker::Date.between(sprint.start_date, sprint.end_date) }
  description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }

  end
end
```

What can I do to achieve what I try to do? What is wrong with what I have tried so far? Any of this questions would be nice to know.

(It is also worth saying that I am also new in rails and ruby)

Comment: I'm amazed your first one didn't blow up, you're using a ternary operator without anything to do if it's false.

Comment: @japed: i'm pretty sure that's just copy/paste mistake. That can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need a block:

```
sprint_scope_change.amount do
  if kind == 0
    Faker::Number.between(1,7)
  elsif kind == 1
    Faker::Number.between(-7,-1)
  else
    Faker::Number.between(-7,7)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick and it's quite simple, I am quite confused as to with what compare an enum, since in the console if I type s.kind == "add" (and it was 0) it returns true but if I type s.kind == 0 it returns false O.o o.O.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need that randomized behaviour? What you want in specs is control. I propose using traits.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sprint_scope_change do

    trait :add do
      kind { 0 }
      amount { random_valid_amount_for_add }
    end

    trait :remove do
      kind { 1 }
      amount { ... }
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.create :sprint_scope_change, :add
```

If you want randomness, again, it's you who's in control

```
let(:random_scope_changes) {
  3.times.map do |i|
    case rand(2)
    when 0 then FactoryGirl.create(:sprint_scope_change, :add)
    when 1 then FactoryGirl.create(:sprint_scope_change, :remove)
      # etc.
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about traits, I decided to go with the other answer since it seems shorter to wirte whether I want control or not.